# How do I grep this data/json?

Tags: json, grep

I am looking to grep this data, but I am completely dyslexic when it comes to grepping. I believe this is a json format, anyway I'm just looking to grep the all of proxy connection information out i.e. from first entry: `165.227.215.62:8080`

```
[{"anonymous":true,"cookies":true,"curl":"http://165.227.215.62:8080","get":true,"ip":"165.227.215.62","isp":"DigitalOcean, LLC","lastChecked":1571849893.7159057,"location":"US","port":8080,"post":true,"protocol":"http","rtt":0.3135862350463867,"ssl":false,"websites":{"amazon":false,"facebook":false,"google":false,"instagram":false,"netflix":false,"nike":false,"shopify":false,"stubhub":false,"supreme":false,"ticketmaster":false,"twitch":false,"twitter":false,"youtube":false}},{"anonymous":true,"cookies":true,"curl":"http://162.243.107.120:8080","get":true,"ip":"162.243.107.120","isp":"DigitalOcean, LLC","lastChecked":1571849944.1533978,"location":"US","port":8080,"post":true,"protocol":"http","rtt":0.3236072063446045,"ssl":false,"websites":{"amazon":false,"facebook":false,"google":false,"instagram":false,"netflix":false,"nike":false,"shopify":false,"stubhub":false,"supreme":false,"ticketmaster":false,"twitch":false,"twitter":false,"youtube":false}},{"anonymous":true,"cookies":true,"curl":"http://162.243.108.141:3128","get":true,"ip":"162.243.108.141","isp":"DigitalOcean, LLC","lastChecked":1571849943.3790483,"location":"US","port":3128,"post":true,"protocol":"http","rtt":0.31897521018981934,"ssl":false,"websites":{"amazon":false,"facebook":false,"google":false,"instagram":false,"netflix":false,"nike":false,"shopify":false,"stubhub":false,"supreme":false,"ticketmaster":false,"twitch":false,"twitter":false,"youtube":false}},{"anonymous":true,"cookies":true,"curl":"http://162.243.108.161:8080","get":true,"ip":"162.243.108.161","isp":"DigitalOcean, LLC","lastChecked":1571849935.5253947,"location":"US","port":8080,"post":true,"protocol":"http","rtt":0.3259437084197998,"ssl":false,"websites":{"amazon":false,"facebook":false,"google":false,"instagram":false,"netflix":false,"nike":false,"shopify":false,"stubhub":false,"supreme":false,"ticketmaster":false,"twitch":false,"twitter":false,"youtube":false}},{"anonymous":true,"cookies":true,"curl":"http://67.205.132.241:8080","get":true,"ip":"67.205.132.241","isp":"DigitalOcean, LLC","lastChecked":1571849936.3941863,"location":"US","port":8080,"post":true,"protocol":"http","rtt":0.33709049224853516,"ssl":false,"websites":{"amazon":false,"facebook":false,"google":false,"instagram":false,"netflix":false,"nike":false,"shopify":false,"stubhub":false,"supreme":false,"ticketmaster":false,"twitch":false,"twitter":false,"youtube":false}}]
```

My Code: `findstr ".*[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\:[0-9][0-9]*" "file.txt`

Comment: Take a look at [tag:jq]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus I mean it's going to be useless to you. But OK...

Comment: findstr-- you using windows?  cygwin?